# ReactJS Recharts: Graph Rendering Issues in Grayed-Out Areas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, visualization, recharts

I want to generate a graph in reactJS like this:-
[image]

But my below code is generating the graph like this:-
[image]

Link to my code - https://codeshare.io/YLD7Pn

```
<div>
      <ResponsiveContainer width={'100%'} height={300}>
      <LineChart width={800} height={400} data={data}>

        {data.map((entry, index) => {
            if (data[index + 1]) {
              // Create ReferenceArea between max and min of each entry
              return (
                <ReferenceArea
                  key={index}
                  x1={entry.DateTime}
                  x2={data[index + 1].DateTime}
                  y1={entry.max}
                  y2={entry.min}
                  fill='#D0D0D0'
                  fillOpacity={0.2}
                />
              );
            }

            return null;

          })}

          {/* Add Line for max and min */}
          <Line dataKey='max' name='Max' stroke='blue' strokeDasharray='5 5' dot={false} />
          <Line dataKey='min' name='Min' stroke='blue' strokeDasharray='5 5' dot={false} />
          {/* Add Line for Value */}
          <Line dataKey='Value' stroke='red' name='Value' dot={false} />

          {/* Add ReferenceDots for points where Value > max */}
          {data.map((entry, index) => {
            if (entry.Value > entry.max) {
              return (
                <ReferenceDot
                  key={index}
                  y={entry.Value}
                  x={entry.DateTime}
                  r={8}
                  fill='red'
                />
              );
            }

            return null;

          })}
        </LineChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </div>
```

Kindly provide the required fix for this issue in REACTJS.